# How to use module System.Text.RegularExpressions in F#?

Tags: regex, types, f#, functional-programming

Im learning how Regex work and there are good examples around the internet but my problems is all the examples use

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

When i try to open The module i get that RegularExpressions is not defined, and when i use FSharp interactive then i can use that module, how can i get to work this module when compiling with Fsharpc.

The error i get :

![enter image description here

Comment: It looks like you're spelling the namespace wrongly in your code judging by the error message.

Comment: In the code i have the same way to open de module and get the error :/

Comment: Which version of F#/.Net are you using? What editor? I can't reproduce this in F#4 / .Net 4.5 / VS2015.

Comment: The answer was right i was using RegularExpression i miss the s, but i was confused cause when i put it in the right way atom with ionide will tell me that is wrong but if you compile with fsharpc it will be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening `System.Text.RegularExpression`

You should be opening `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Notice the `s` on the end.

Comment: Yeah you are right, Atom with ionide was confusing me cause when i put the module right atom will tell me it is wrong but y compile it and it work... Thank you